# How to check if update query was executed or not in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, update

I have an update query in MySQL and I want to return true or false based on whether my update query was executed or not. Is there any way we can find whether the update query is executed?

```
UPDATE table SET table.name = "Anthony" WHERE table.id = 3;
IF (queryUpdated) THEN
    SELECT 1 AS updated;
ELSE
    SELECT 0 AS updated;
END IF;
```

Comment: *whether my update query was executed or not.* ??? If you call this query execution then it was executed (of course if MySQL is accessible). This execution can be successful or may result in some error. If it is sucessful then there can be matched rows or not, if they exists then they can be updated by fact or not... What do you want to know precisely?

Comment: Read the details of `ROWS_AFFECTED`.

Comment: What will you then do with the true/false result?  If you feed that into another SQL, maybe the two statements can be combined??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want the [`ROW_COUNT()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count)

```
UPDATE table SET table.name = "Anthony" WHERE table.id = 3;
SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS updated;
```

Comment: Note ROW_COUNT() returns 0 if there was no row matching `id=3` or also if there was a matching row, but the name on that row was already 'Anthony'. Either way, the update accomplished no net change.